# Problems with site loading and sql connections when disabling old SSL on Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, ssl, iis, server

We have some Server 2008 R2 machines (I know, we are going to migrate to new servers soon hopefully) that we are trying to disable old SSL protocols and ciphers as per a security recommendation, and I'm having some unexpected trouble. I expected that older versions of IE wouldn't be able to load websites served from this servers IIS, but actually I'm finding that Chrome v78 can't connect to the site, where IE11 still can. Also that server cannot connect to SQL 2008 instances (10.0.5520) on another server, and I'm having trouble finding what is the latest versions of protocols and ciphers I can use to make this work. Below is what we have set the server to support, and I've tried turning back on TLS 1.1 and the TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA ciphers but no luck so far and I have to reboot the server each time to test so it's a pain, so wondering if anyone has any insight?

[image: IIS Crypto Settings]

[image]

Chrome can't load site at all:
[image]

SQL Server won't connect:
[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server 2008 (which, by the way, is now completely unsupported, and you really should be looking at upgrade paths). Windows Server 2008 has less than 3 months left of (extended) support  as well.

Comment: SQL Server is 10.0.5520 (SP3), and yes we are trying to migrate but waiting on others to complete their tasks to coordinate it.

Comment: Well, here's a double whammy for you then. Not only are you running a completely unsupported version of SQL Server (SQL Server 2008) but the version you are running is a long way behind the patch curve. Yes, TLS1.2 support was added to SQL Server 2008, but that was added with SP4. The simple statement is, your unpatched and unsupported version of SQL Server simply does not support TLS1.2. You even need to get those patches install or that upgrade done. ASAP. [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)

Comment: Saying IE 11 without its underlying operating system is meaningless. IE 11 on certain Windows release does support TLS 1.2. To troubleshoot the SQL Server connection, use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the actual TLS handshake packets. That should give you the initial data on what to check next.

Comment: IE 11 on Win 10, Win 8.1 and Win 7 all load the site fine. My question is why wouldn't chrome load it if IE 11 does.

Comment: But yes, I will try Wireshark thanks. I was trying Fiddler, but didn't see anything jump out at me.

Comment: And yes I know I need to replace this old sql server and I know 2008 doesn’t support 1.2, the question is how to find the highest it does support for now until I can upgrade.

Comment: @BrentKilboy, in my opinion, this issue is happen because of the SQL server you could refer this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find any info, I had to just test a whole bunch of settings.
I found the SQL Server 2008 only supported TLS 1.0.

I found the problem with Chrome is that it's handshake didn't support some of the ciphers, so when I turned off almost all of them, IE still accepted the ones I had on, but Chrome didn't.

And another thing I found is that IIS Cryto tool is deceiving, because it lets you check a bunch of protocols that aren't even on the server.

I used this SSL scan tool from https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan/releases to find out what the server was actually outputting.

And yes I'm going to upgrade from 2008 soon.

I also realized that the SSL for public facing is actually being served from a proxy server, so these are only for internal SSL communications that I need to config directly on the app server.